# Why is the SVD named so?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, math-history, svd

The SVD stands for Singular Value Decomposition. After decomposing a data matrix $\mathbf X$ using SVD, it results in three matrices, two matrices with the singular vectors $\mathbf U$ and $\mathbf V$, and one singular value matrix whose diagonal elements are the singular values. But I want to know why those values are named as singular values. Is there any connection between a singular matrix and these singular values?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#History

Comment: Hi @arbautjc, my question was not about history of singular values. Why those values are called as singular values. Is there any proper scientific reason? or are they connected with singular matrix (non-invertible).

Comment: "Is there any connection between singular matrix and these singular values?" - in name, no. But it is true that if the matrix has singular values equal to zero, then the matrix is singular.

Comment: @S.P I know, but it's to be found in *history* of mathematics.

Comment: ["One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA&feature=youtu.be&t=296) -- Feynman

Answer (score 12):

From *[On the Early History of the Singular Value Decomposition](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/1035134)* by Pete Stewart:

> The term "singular value" seems to have come from the literature on integral equations. A little after the appearance of Schmidt's paper, Bateman refers to numbers that are essentially the reciprocals of the eigenvalues of the kernel as singular values. Picard combined Schmidt's results with Riesz's theorem on the strong convergence of generalized Fourier series to establish a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of solutions of integral equations.
>
> In a later paper on the same subject, he notes that for symmetric kernels Schmidt's eigenvalues are real and in this case (but not in general) he calls them singular values. By 1937, Smithies was referring to singular values of an integral equation in our modern sense of the word. Even at this point, usage had not stabilized. In 1949, Weyl speaks of the "two kinds of eigenvalues of a linear transformation," and in a 1969 translation of a 1965 Russian treatise on nonselfadjoint operators Gohberg and Krein refer to the "s-numbers" of an operator.

See the paper for more fascinating accounts on how SVD came to be, even before the seminal paper of Golub/Kahan.

Comment: I have long forgotten the term "s-number". Your answer makes me feel nostalgic!

Comment: Why, thank you. Reading Pete Stewart's paper made me feel fuzzy, too. On the other hand, nowadays I'm doing way more linear algebra and way less operator theory...

Answer (score 2):

From Schwartzman's [The Words of Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883855119):

> **singular** (adjective), **singularity** (noun): from Latin *singulus* "separate, individual, single," from the Indo-European root *sem-* "one, as one."
>   If there is just a single example of something, that example becomes special, so *singular* took on the meaning "out of the ordinary." [...]
>   The meaning "out of the ordinary, troublesome," explains why a singular matrix is a square matrix whose determinant equals $0$ rather than $1$, as the etymology implies.

Also, note that the terms *singular matrix* and *singular value* are contemporary. They made their first [documented appearance](http://jeff560.tripod.com/s.html) in 1907 and 1908, respectively.

As such, I'd guess that *singular values* are called like that just because they are indeed out of the ordinary. They provide a nice invariant for any complex valued matrix.

Answer (score 0):

"Singular" means "noninvertible," and any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of matrix $M$ makes $M - \lambda I$ a singular (that is, noninvertible) matrix.

The singular values $\sigma$ of $A$ are the values for which the matrices $$A^\top A - \sigma^2 I\\ AA^\top  - \sigma^2 I$$ are singular (noninvertible).

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value#History :

> This concept [of singular values] was introduced by Erhard Schmidt in 1907. Schmidt called singular values "eigenvalues" at that time. The name "singular value" was first quoted by Smithies in 1937.

Additionally (and this may simply be fortuitous coincidence), the *singular vectors* of $A$ are two sets of vectors, $\{v_i\}$ and $\{u_i\}$ , such that for any $v_i$, then $Av_i = \sigma_iu_i$.  The image of each singular vector ($v$) is therefore a multiple of a *single* singluar vector ($u$)!  Thus, *singular vectors* are vectors that map to multiples of *single* singular vectors.