# Matrix expression with pseudo-inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

If $M$ is symmetric and non-singular, and $G$ is non-symmetric and singular, is there any simple expression for:

$$G^{T}\left(GMG^{T}\right)^{\dagger}G$$

where the $\dagger$ denotes the pseudo-inverse?  In general, the $G$'s do not cancel.

I don't need an explicit expression for the pseudo-inverse by itself, just the product above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, as $G$ has no special structure and it is unrelated to $M$, I don't think you can make the expression very much simpler.

**Edit.** In some cases some slight simplifications are possible. For instances,

- if $G$ is also an orthogonal projection, the expression is equal to $(GMG^T)^\dagger$;
- if $(G^\dagger G) M (G^\dagger G)$ has the same rank as $G$ (e.g. when $M$ is positive/negative definite), you may slightly simplify the expression to $\left((G^\dagger G)M(G^\dagger G)\right)^\dagger$.

*Proof of the second case.* Let $G=USV^T$ be a SVD and $D=SS^\dagger$. So, if $G$ has rank $k$ and $S=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k,0,\ldots,0)$, then $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,\ldots,1,0,\ldots,0)$. Thus
\begin{align}
G^T(GMG^T)^\dagger G
&= VSU^T(USV^TMVSU^T)^\dagger USV^T\\
&= VS(SV^TMVS)^\dagger SV^T\tag{1}\\
&= VS(S(DV^TMVD)S)^\dagger SV^T,\tag{2}
\end{align}
where line $(1)$ holds because in general, $(QX)^\dagger \equiv X^\dagger Q^\dagger$ whenever $Q$ is unitary. Now, by assumption, $G$ and $(G^\dagger G) M (G^\dagger G) $ have the same ranks, i.e. $S$ and $DV^TMVD$ have the same ranks. Since each of $S$ and $DV^TMVD$ is a direct sum of a $k\times k$ invertible matrix and a zero block, in calculating $S(S(DV^TMVD)S)^\dagger S$, the pseudo inverse is just a usual matrix inverse in the leading $k\times k$ subblock. Thus $(2)$ gives
\begin{align}
G^T(GMG^T)^\dagger G
&= V(DV^TMVD)^\dagger V^T\\
&= \left(VDV^TMVDV^T\right)^\dagger\tag{3}\\
&= \left((G^\dagger G)M(G^\dagger G)\right)^\dagger,
\end{align}
where $(3)$ again is due to the property that $(QX)^\dagger \equiv X^\dagger Q^\dagger$ whenever $Q$ is unitary.

Comment: Is that "slightly simplified" relation correct? Is there a proof?  And did you mean "all NON-singular values of G"?  Meaning all the non-zeros in the diagonal matrix of the SVD of G are equal to one, right?

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering about the terminology.  You're calling the NON-zero values singular. But I thought it was having zeros in the diagonal matrix of the SVD is was made a matrix singular.

Comment: I said in the Question that G is singular.  But why are the non-zero values called singular when it's the zeros that make the matrix singular?  Weird.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing how the simplified relation comes out of the SVD.

Comment: @JerryGuern See [Why the SVD is named so…](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360214/why-the-svd-is-named-so) for the nomenclature or history of singular values.

Comment: Nope, that relation is not correct. He's a counter example:
M = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {3, 5, 6}};
G = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};

Comment: @JerryGuern Uhh, sorry, I've misread the question. I thought $M$ was positive definite.

Comment: My counter examples fails if I add an Identity Matrix to M to make it positive definite.  Can you explain why this relation would work iff M is pos def?  I'm intrigued.

Comment: I generated a separate question about this.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444777/cant-understand-this-pseudo-inverse-relation

Comment: @JerryGuern It's because every principal submatrix of a positive definite matrix is invertible, so that $(GMG^T)^\dagger$ is in essence (i.e. by a change of orthonormal basis) a usual matrix inverse in the position of a principal submatrix. For more details, see my new edit.

Comment: Thank for you extended Answer; it's taking me some time to absorb it.  I've posted a related question that might interest you, too.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445911/how-to-optimize-a-singular-covariance-weighted-residual