# What does Singular value represent in the context of Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Regarding SVD: Why is it called Singular Value and what does that value represent?
And where does the SVD play a part in applications?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [Why the SVD is named so...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360214/why-the-svd-is-named-so) it sounds like the terminology is mostly caused by historical baggage rather than it really having much mathematical significance.

Anyway, most applications are based on the property that $\sigma_n=\max_{\| x \|=1,x \perp v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}} \| Ax \|$. The right singular vectors $v_n$ are the corresponding maximizers (which aren't unique), while $Av_n=\sigma_n u_n$. Thus you find the direction in the domain that $A$ makes the biggest, then you search among vectors orthogonal to that for the direction in the domain that $A$ makes biggest, and so on. You can show from this definition that the $u_n$ are also mutually orthogonal, thus this provides an orthogonal coordinate system for the domain and in general a different orthogonal coordinate system for the codomain such that in this pair of systems $A$ is diagonal with nonnegative entries.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful.